# Remove Genesis Default Sidebar not working

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I have a custom archive template: archive-ssbd_birds.php

I want to replace the default sidebar with one I created using the Genesis Simple Sidebars plugin.

[Page Link](http://blog.sweet-seed.com/birds/)

This is what I have:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'genesis_do_sidebar' ); 

add_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'bird_directory_sidebar' );
   function bird_directory_sidebar() {
     dynamic_sidebar( 'bird-directory' );
}
```

The new sidebar (bird-directory) is coming in fine. It's the light gray box that says New Sidebar.

But the default sidebar is still there underneath it. (starting with the search box and everything underneath it.)

I just want to get rid of that default sidebar

Thanks in advance for taking a look! Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
remove_action( 'get_header', 'ss_sidebars_init' );
remove_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'genesis_do_sidebar' );
```